# How to create web-part or web-app from bootstrap carousel

Tags: image-display, boot-strap

Is there anyway that I can create a web part or a web app so that I can use a bootstrap carousel on a SharePoint site. Currently I have a carousel but the master page is using a bootstrap theme, however I want to get rid of the theme but still keep the bootstrap carousel on the site. Anyway to do this? I've downloaded the carousel component by itself.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap theme is required for the Bootstrap Carousel, but only on the page where you use the Carousel.
If you remove it from the MasterPage you have to use another method to load it on the required page.

- (SP Designer) Edit the specific page and link the Bootstrap CSS file like you now do in the MasterPage
- Add the Bootstrap CSS dynamically with code on the page

  - with a Content Editor Webpart which adds all CSS to the page
  - With SharePoints SOD (Script on Demand) functions which add the CSS link to the page
  - ...

If you're not comfortable with scripting just copy/pasting all Bootstrap CSS into a Content Editor Webpart might be the best option *I do not know if the CEWP has limitation on size*